# Printing out sentences in JLabel

Tags: java, components, jlabel

How to print out a new sentence or line in JLabel, without changing the last line that was printed? or do I have to use another component?

Comment: use setText(getText() + current text)

Comment: JTextArea is more suited for multiline text. Nevertheless, you need to get content currently displayed by the component (getText()), concatenate with new content and set the value to display (setText()).

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText() to retrieve what's already present in the JLabel, and then setText() to set the new value.

So to add something to the end, you'd do

label.setText(label.getText()+"new line");

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get desired output.

```
public class CreateJLabelWithBorder extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JTextField textField;
JLabel label;

public CreateJLabelWithBorder() {
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    textField = new JTextField(20);
    add(textField);
    textField.addActionListener(this);
    label = new JLabel("Hello world");
    add(label);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (!textField.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (label.getText() != null) {
            String text = textField.getText() + "<br>" + label.getText();
            label.setText("<html> <body>" + text + "</body></html>" + "<br>");
            textField.setText("");
        } else {
            String text = textField.getText();
            label.setText("<html> <body>" + text + "</body></html>" + "<br>");
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new CreateJLabelWithBorder();
    // frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(500, 700);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}}
```